# Table and Column resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm, in situation where a Grid kind of table is done using Angularjs and Javascript, not with e.g. ng-Grid or Datatables.net.

Are there any possibilities to implement column resizing into that kind of table?

I found a jQuery component called colResizable, has anyone used it and does it work with AngularJS? Or are there any other utilities that could do column resizing?

Br

Michael

Comment: would be great if you can show what you have tried.

Comment: try wrapping plugin in a directive....provide a demo in plunker

Comment: Yes, Table is really a HTML table nothing else. That's what we have to deal with. So, are there any ways to implement table column resizing with a Directive or jQuery plugin?